# Hook woocommerce price in backend order edition

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I need to change item product prices in Woocommerce **Backend** Order. I tried tu use the following hook, but I have a problem trying to obtain the **order id**. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

```
function my_custom_prices ($price, $product)
{
    if ( !is_admin() || ( is_admin() && is_post_type_archive() ) ) return $price;

    global $post, $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $post_id );
    $user_id = $order->user_id; 
    $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

    if ( in_array( 'my_role', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        return $price * 2; 
    }
    else {
        return $price;
    }

}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'my_custom_prices ', 10, 2);
```

**Complete problem:**

The complete problem is as follows. I am using a plugin that adds a field to the product called wholesale price. If the customer has the wholesale customer role, the order uses those prices. The plugin works fine, but it does not take the price in the backend. I talked to the author and it's something they do not plan to change yet. My client needs to modify the orders. But when it enters the backend, it takes the common price, not the wholesaler. I need to do something in the backend that allows me to detect if the order is from a client with a wholesale customer role. If yes, take the correct price when adding products. There is more information on the discussion with the author here. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wholesale-prices-in-backend-editing-orders/ Thank you very much for the help you can give me.

**Options:**

**woocommerce_get_price**: does not work because I cannot obtain the customer id

**woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta**: nice option, but I could not find a sample

**Button**: nice option, but I do not know how can I change the price. I tryed the follow:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons', 'action_aplicar_mayoristas', 10, 1);

function action_aplicar_mayoristas( $order )
{
    echo '<button type="button" onclick="document.post.submit();" class="button button-primary generate-items">Aplicar precios mayoristas</button>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="1" name="aplicar_mayoristas" />';
};

add_action('save_post', 'aplicar_mayoristas', 10, 3);

function aplicar_mayoristas($post_id, $post, $update){
    $slug = 'shop_order';
    if(is_admin()){
            if ( $slug != $post->post_type ) {
                    return;
            }
            if(isset($_POST['aplicar_mayoristas']) && $_POST['aplicar_mayoristas']){


$order = wc_get_order( $post_id); 
//$order_id = $order->get_user_id();

// Iterating through each "line" items in the order
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {

   //$item_data->set_subtotal("798");
   $item_data->set_price("798");
//->set_price($custom_price);
}


                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

The hook that you are using is not for orders, but only for products, and is made to change the displayed prices only. So you will not get the order ID with it.

You could change the price display in many hooks, but if you want to change order item prices for real (not only the displayed formatted prices), you should trigger this prices changes when order is updated for example.

In this case you can use a custom function hooked in `save_post` action hook:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'change_order_item_prices', 11, 1 );
function change_order_item_prices( $post_id ) {

    // If this is an autosave (has not been submitted).
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( 'shop_order' == $_POST[ 'post_type' ] ){
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_order', $post_id ) )
            return $post_id;
    } else {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
            return $post_id;
    }

    ## ------------------- Changing prices Start code ------------------- ##

    ## ===> HERE define the targeted user role
    $user_role = 'my_role';

    ## ===> HERE define the rate multiplier (for price calculations)
    $multiplier = 2;

    // If this Order items prices have already been updated, we exit
    $items_prices_updated = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'line_item_updated', true );
    if( ! empty( $items_prices_updated ) ) return $post_id; // Exit

    $order = new WC_Order( $post_id ); // Get the order object
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the user ID
    $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id ); // Get the user data

    // Check the user role
    if ( ! in_array( $user_role, $user_data->roles ) ) return;

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
        $item_data = $item->get_data(); // The item data
        $taxes = array();

        foreach( $item_data['taxes'] as $key_tax => $values ){
            if( ! empty( $values ) ){
                foreach( $values as $key => $tax_price ){
                    $taxes[$key_tax][$key] = floatval($tax_price) * $multiplier;
                }
            }
        }
        $new_line_subtotal = floatval( $item_data['subtotal'] ) * $multiplier;
        $new_line_subt_tax = floatval( $item_data['subtotal_tax'] ) * $multiplier;
        $new_line_total = floatval( $item_data['total'] ) * $multiplier;
        $new_line_total_tax = floatval( $item_data['total_tax'] ) * $multiplier;

        // Update Order item prices
        $item->set_subtotal($new_line_subtotal);
        $item->set_subtotal_tax($new_line_subt_tax);
        $item->set_total($new_line_total);
        $item->set_total_tax($new_line_total_tax);
        $item->set_taxes($taxes);
        // Save the updated data
        $item->save();
    }
    // Udpate order totals and cache
    $order->calculate_totals();
    
    // We mark the order as updated (to avoid repetition)
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'line_item_updated', true );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and and finally works.

I have added a security to avoid the order items to be updated twice.

> The method `$order->calculate_totals();` slow down the process a little bit… It's normal as it will calculate totals, update data and refresh caches.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is not working. I do not why. But I am using to take some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: @jpussacq I am still working on the code… Give me some time please. I am testing everything. I will have something working anyway, so be just a little patient, because it's quite complicated.

Comment: Thanks! Sameone sugested to use woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta I think it could be a good option, exactly what I need. But Icannot fin a sample code. Do you know that hook?

Comment: @jpussacq Why do you think that `woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta` is exactly the hook that you need… You haven't specify in your question when or how you would like to update order item prices.

Comment: Oh sorry. I tryed to explain when I said "Woocommerce Backend Order". In the backend, when I edit an order. When I add a product, I need to change the price. And the business rule need to know who is the customer id of the order. Please tell me if I'm not clear. Thanks

Comment: I added "complete problem" in the question. Thanks

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your time. It is very difficult for me to find Woocommerce documentation and I do not know how to solve problems. I can see that you have a lot of knowledge and experience, so thank you very much. I need to ask you two questions. If you prefer a chat, there's no problem. 1) Will this code be executed when you press "Update" and it applies to all the items of the order? 2) Is there any possibility to calculate the price within "woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta"? I think it will have better usability.

Comment: @jpussacq Hello … 1) Yes and yes … 2)  `woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta` is not maid for that, meaning that is used with the edit ajax functionalities of WC on order items, when order is not locked (so not useful for your case).… My code answer works just perfectly (I think) … You will be able to add a custom field like a check box to enable the functionality. if you need to chat contact me on skype chat (my ID is `marsloic` )… Please don't forget to accept this answer (and if is not you, to upvote it). Thanks.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec. I nedd a variation of this code. Could you hep me? I added a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192338/woocommerce-backend-change-order-proces-to-new-prices Thanks in advance

Comment: I need exactly that. A button within the order in the backend that you update the prices of that order, taking the values of the prices of the products. It is a manual operation of an administrator. To update prices on delayed orders.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be debugged.

1. $post_id - there is not such variable or parameter inside your function. So, use $post->ID instead.
2. do

   var_dump( (array) $user->roles);

before the

```
if (in_array( 'my_role', (array) $user->roles ) )
```

line. And make sure that my_role exists in that array.

3. Temporary comment this line for debugging purpose:

   // if (is_admin() && is_post_type_archive())

Then you will see the reason and able to be fix it.

Comment: The problem is I need to get the user id of the customer. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: $user_id=get_current_user_id();

Comment: Thanks! Is this the customer (not the current user) in woocommerce_get_price filter ? I am asking because I am in the backend logged as admin.

Comment: You can use $order-get_user_id() for that